# How to Integrate Easy Paisa Checkout with React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

`

```
  const sampleString = `amount=250&emailAddress=&orderRef
  Num=1234&paymentMethod=InitialRequest&storeId=20986&timeStamp=2022-10-31T21:53:00`;

  const hashKey = "182734891798";
  const keyBuffer = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(hashKey);
  const inputBuffer = aesjs.padding.pkcs7.pad(
    aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(sampleString)
  );
  const escEcb = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ecb(keyBuffer);
  const encryptedBytes = escEcb.encrypt(inputBuffer);
  const encryptedData = Buffer.from(encryptedBytes).toString("base64");
  // console.log("====>", encryptedData);


 const requestBody = `storeId=20986&orderId=1234&transactionAmount=250&transactionType=InitialRequest&
  encryptedHashRequest=kQK2X8LkbnkrrmHhF1LH5S9JzmsWjRmrEGcUmK69LHgn78bVKobGIk95sCHlbA9xjojthdzPquZAVOn%2F
  xuQ%2Bh3fQN6zBkC%2FZhefMomJ%2BQzxsTLBu7xcbKdtwpoao8zRtW2htW4Fy45uIAUM%2Bw2hxnA%3D%3D`;


  const requestHeader = {
    // Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  };

  return (

    <>
      <WebView
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
        source={{
          uri: `https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/tpg`,
          headers: requestHeader,
          body: requestBody,
          method: "POST",
        }}
      />
```

`

i have tried all the thing methods to integrate Easypaisa checkout payment gateway with react native app but unable to get success please help and let me know what wrong i have done ..
[image: code]

[EasyPaisa Integration guide open source download from here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YJE4zqJCSh2KUsuzM8st33oeYUQPe60Q/view?usp=sharing/)